# Where can I find guidance in setting up free wifi Internet access for our municipality?

Tags: site-administration, community-organizing

I would like to submit a proposal to my municipality for them to offer free wifi Internet to the township residents. They do not have an exclusivity agreement for Internet service with the current [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider), just exclusivity for cable tv service.

Internet access is essential nowadays as even the [public education system requires more and more of the assignments, instruction, and testing online](https://www.edweek.org/ew/issues/technology-in-education/index.html).  So, if a public institution paid for by tax buyer requires its residents to use a communications network, it is unjust for that network to be a private enterprise monopoly.  This particularly relevant when these [ISPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) are using monopoly power to get rid of [Net Neutrality](https://vivipins.com/net-neutrality-what-you-need-know-now/).

I don't want to re-invent the wheel here and I have seen free wifi offered in some town and college campuses.  I need guidance and assistance in this regard.

I apologize if this is not the best forum for the question. Please advise if so and which SE site would be a better fit.